# Teradata create table auto-increment column error

Tags: mysql, database, csv, teradata

I am trying to import my CSV file into Teradata using Teradata's Fastload script. 
I also tried adding an auto-increment column.
This is my CSV file:

```
Word,country,sale,week
hi,USA,26.17,11/22/15-11/28/15
bye,USA,16.5,11/22/15-11/28/15
```

code snippet

```
String tableName = "my_db.mytable";
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "," +
                            "NO FALLBACK," +
                            "NO BEFORE JOURNAL," +
                            "NO AFTER JOURNAL," +
                            "CHECKSUM = DEFAULT" +
                            "(" +
                            " id decimal(10,0) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 NO CYCLE),"+
                            " word VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET UNICODE," +
                            " country VARCHAR(50)," +
                            " sale FLOAT," +
                            " week VARCHAR(30)" +
                            ") " +
                          "PRIMARY INDEX (id)";

    // INSERT statement
    String insertTable = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Error i got:

```
Row 1 in FastLoad table my_db.mytable_ERR_1 contains the following data: 
ErrorCode=2673
ErrorFieldName=F_id
ActualDataParcelLength=55
DataParcel: byte array length 55 (0x37), offset 0 (0x0), dump length 55 (0x37)
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a FastLoad script, is this part of a JDBC-FastLoad?

> 2673 The source parcel length does not match data that was defined.

Your input data is a comma-delimited text, thus you must define all columns as VARCHAR.

And there are **four** columns in your input file, but you specify **five** in the `INSERT`. As the name implies a `GENERATED ALWAYS` sequence is automatically created.